# GROUP BY expression must contain at least... UNION Query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, join, union

I have a large query that is actually a view and it worked in Oracle but doesn't in MS-SQL Server.  The second half of the UNION query intentionally will have hard coded values.

I'm posting the original query that worked in Oracle 11g just fine although I tried another method that didn't have the two hard-coded values of 0, 'Financials'.  That attempt is posted at the bottom.

The error I receive is: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

```
   SELECT 
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.TXN_ID                AS TXN_ID,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.REC_PROC_ID           AS RECORD_PROC_ID,
   RECOVERYPROCESS.REC_PROC_NAME           AS RECORD_PROC_NAME, 
   RECOVERYPROCESS.REC_PROC_TYPE_ID        AS RECORD_PROC_TYPE_ID,
   RECOVERYPROCTYPE.REC_PROC_TYPE_NAME     AS RECORD_PROC_TYPE_NAME,
   RECOVERYPROCESS.REC_PROC_SEQ            AS RECORD_PROC_SEQUENCE_NUM,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_ID                AS SERVICE_ID,
   SERVICECATALOG.SVC_REF                  AS SERVICE_REFERENCE,
   SERVICECATALOG.SVC_DESC                 AS SERVICE_DESCRIPTION,
   SERVICECATALOG.SDG_ID                   AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_ID,
   STUDYGROUP1.SDG_REF                     AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_REF,
   STUDYGROUP1.SDG_DESC                    AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_PER_ID            AS SERVICE_PERIOD_ID,
   PERIOD1.PER_REF                         AS SERVICE_PERIOD_REFERENCE,
   PERIOD1.PER_DESC                        AS SERVICE_PERIOD_DESCRIPT,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_SCN_ID            AS SERVICE_SCENARIO_ID,
   SCENARIO1.SCN_DESC                      AS SERVICE_SCENARIO_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_RATE              AS SERVICE_RATE,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.REC_TRANS_TYPE_ID     AS TRANS_TYPE_ID,
   RECOVERYTRANSTYPE.REC_TRANS_TYPE_NAME   AS TRANS_TYPE_NAME,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.CUST_ACCT_REF         AS CUSToMER_ACCOUNT,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.ORG_REF               AS ORGANIZATION_REFERENCE,
   ORGANIZATION.ORG_DESC                   AS ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_ID                       AS STUDY_GROUP_ID,                      
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_REF                      AS STUDY_GROUP_REFERENCE,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_DESC                     AS STUDY_GROUP_DESCRIPT,
   SUM(RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.REC_AMT)          AS TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_ID                AS VOLUME_ID,
   VOLUMECATALOG.VOL_REF                   AS VOLUME_REFERENCE,
   VOLUMECATALOG.VOL_DESC                  AS VOLUME_DESCRIPTION,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_PER_ID            AS VOLUME_PERIOD_ID,
   PERIOD.PER_REF                          AS VOLUME_PERIOD_REFERENCE,
   PERIOD.PER_DESC                         AS VOLUME_PERIOD_DESCRIPT,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_SCN_ID            AS VOLUME_SCENARIO_ID,
   SCENARIO.SCN_DESC                       AS VOLUME_SCENARIO_DESCRIPT,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_QTY               AS VOLUME_QUANTITY
   FROM RECOVERYTXNLEDGER
   INNER JOIN SCENARIO SCENARIO1 ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_SCN_ID = SCENARIO1.SCN_ID
   INNER JOIN SERVICECATALOG ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_ID = SERVICECATALOG.SVC_ID
   INNER JOIN STUDYGROUP STUDYGROUP1 ON SERVICECATALOG.SDG_ID = STUDYGROUP1.SDG_ID
   INNER JOIN PERIOD PERIOD1 ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_PER_ID = PERIOD1.PER_ID
   INNER JOIN RECOVERYPROCESS ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.REC_PROC_ID = RECOVERYPROCESS.REC_PROC_ID
   INNER JOIN RECOVERYPROCTYPE ON RECOVERYPROCESS.REC_PROC_TYPE_ID = RECOVERYPROCTYPE.REC_PROC_TYPE_ID
   INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.ORG_REF = ORGANIZATION.ORG_REF
   INNER JOIN STUDYGROUP ON ORGANIZATION.SDG_ID = STUDYGROUP.SDG_ID
   INNER JOIN RECOVERYTRANSTYPE ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.REC_TRANS_TYPE_ID = RECOVERYTRANSTYPE.REC_TRANS_TYPE_ID
   INNER JOIN VOLUMECATALOG ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_ID = VOLUMECATALOG.VOL_ID
   INNER JOIN PERIOD ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_PER_ID = PERIOD.PER_ID
   INNER JOIN SCENARIO ON RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_SCN_ID = SCENARIO.SCN_ID
   GROUP BY 
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.REC_PROC_ID,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.TXN_ID,
   RECOVERYPROCESS.REC_PROC_NAME,
   RECOVERYPROCESS.REC_PROC_TYPE_ID,
   RECOVERYPROCTYPE.REC_PROC_TYPE_NAME,
   RECOVERYPROCESS.REC_PROC_SEQ,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_ID,
   SERVICECATALOG.SVC_REF,
   SERVICECATALOG.SVC_DESC,
   SERVICECATALOG.SDG_ID,
   STUDYGROUP1.SDG_REF,
   STUDYGROUP1.SDG_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_PER_ID,
   PERIOD1.PER_REF,
   PERIOD1.PER_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_SCN_ID,
   SCENARIO1.SCN_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.SVC_RATE,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.REC_TRANS_TYPE_ID,
   RECOVERYTRANSTYPE.REC_TRANS_TYPE_NAME,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.CUST_ACCT_REF,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.ORG_REF,
   ORGANIZATION.ORG_DESC,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_ID,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_REF,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_ID,
   VOLUMECATALOG.VOL_REF,
   VOLUMECATALOG.VOL_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_PER_ID,
   PERIOD.PER_REF,
   PERIOD.PER_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_SCN_ID,
   SCENARIO.SCN_DESC,
   RECOVERYTXNLEDGER.VOL_QTY
   UNION
   SELECT 
   NULL                        AS TXN_ID,
   NULL                        AS REC_PROC_ID,
   NULL                        AS RECORD_PROC_NAME,
   NULL                        AS RECORD_PROC_TYPE_ID,
   NULL                        AS RECORD_PROC_TYPE_NAME,
   NULL                        AS RECORD_PROC_SEQUENCE_NUM,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_ID,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_REFERENCE,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_DESCRIPTION,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_ID           AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_ID,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_REF          AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_REF,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_DESC         AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_DESC,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_PERIOD_ID,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_PERIOD_REFERENCE,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_PERIOD_DESCRIPT,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_SCENARIO_ID,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_SCENARIO_DESC,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_RATE,
   0                           AS TRANS_TYPE_ID, 
   'Financials'                AS TRANS_TYPE_NAME, 
   NULL                        AS CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT,
   Financials.ORG_REF          AS ORGANIZATION_REFERENCE, 
   Organization.ORG_DESC       AS ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION, 
   StudyGroup.SDG_ID           AS STUDY_GROUP_ID, 
   StudyGroup.SDG_REF          AS STUDY_GROUP_REFERENCE, 
   StudyGroup.SDG_DESC         AS STUDY_GROUP_DESCRIPT, 
   Sum(Financials.GL_AMOUNT)   AS TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, 
   Financials.FIN_ID           AS VOLUME_ID,
   FINANCIALS.GLACCT_REF       AS VOLUME_REFERENCE,
   FINANCIALS.GLACCT_DESC      AS VOLUME_DESCRIPTION,
   Financials.FIN_PER_ID       AS VOLUME_PERIOD_ID, 
   Period.PER_REF              AS VOLUME_PERIOD_REFERENCE, 
   Period.PER_DESC             AS VOLUME_PERIOD_DESCRIPT, 
   Financials.FIN_SCN_ID       AS VOLUME_SCENARIO_ID, 
   Scenario.SCN_DESC           AS VOLUME_SCENARIO_DESCRIPT,
   NULL                        AS VOLUME_QUANTITY
   FROM (((StudyGroup INNER JOIN Organization ON StudyGroup.SDG_ID = Organization.SDG_ID) 
   INNER JOIN Financials ON Organization.ORG_REF = Financials.ORG_REF) 
   INNER JOIN Scenario ON Financials.FIN_SCN_ID = Scenario.SCN_ID) 
   INNER JOIN Period ON Financials.FIN_PER_ID = Period.PER_ID
   GROUP BY 
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_ID,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_REF,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_DESC,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   0,
   'Financials',
   NULL,
   FINANCIALS.ORG_REF,
   ORGANIZATION.ORG_DESC,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_ID,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_REF,
   STUDYGROUP.SDG_DESC,
   FINANCIALS.FIN_ID,
   FINANCIALS.GLACCT_REF,
   FINANCIALS.GLACCT_DESC,
   FINANCIALS.FIN_PER_ID,
   PERIOD.PER_REF,
   PERIOD.PER_DESC,
   FINANCIALS.FIN_SCN_ID,
   SCENARIO.SCN_DESC,
   NULL
```

I did try replacing the two literals with:

```
CASE WHEN StudyGroup.SDG_ID >= 0 THEN 0 ELSE 0 END AS TRANS_TYPE_ID, 
CASE WHEN StudyGroup.SDG_ID >= 0 THEN 'Financials' ELSE 'Financials' END AS TRANS_TYPE_NAME,
```

and in the GROUP BY:

```
CASE WHEN StudyGroup.SDG_ID >= 0 THEN 0 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN StudyGroup.SDG_ID >= 0 THEN 'Financials' ELSE 'Financials' END,
```

Thanks...

Comment: Leave the literals out of the group by. It makes no sense. Not at all sure what you are trying to accomplish with those case expressions that always return the same value.

Comment: I was trying to get the query to work. I had came across another post on here that provided them as a working example, so I just used that to see if mine would work too.  Okay, I pulled the literals out and still have the same error message. BTW, I'm asking for help, not criticism.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using table aliases especially with larger queries like this. It makes reading it a lot easier to see what is going on. I tweaked your second query a bit and added some aliases. I then realized you have the same 3 columns in your query twice and you were grouping by them multiple times. This won't affect the outcome but it is a bit less confusing. I am guessing that the problem is in your second query so I would isolate that one and get it working before you add it to the UNION.

```
SELECT 
   NULL                        AS TXN_ID,
   NULL                        AS REC_PROC_ID,
   NULL                        AS RECORD_PROC_NAME,
   NULL                        AS RECORD_PROC_TYPE_ID,
   NULL                        AS RECORD_PROC_TYPE_NAME,
   NULL                        AS RECORD_PROC_SEQUENCE_NUM,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_ID,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_REFERENCE,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_DESCRIPTION,
   sg.SDG_ID           AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_ID,
   sg.SDG_REF          AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_REF,
   sg.SDG_DESC         AS SERVICE_STUDY_GROUP_DESC,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_PERIOD_ID,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_PERIOD_REFERENCE,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_PERIOD_DESCRIPT,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_SCENARIO_ID,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_SCENARIO_DESC,
   NULL                        AS SERVICE_RATE,
   0                           AS TRANS_TYPE_ID, 
   'Financials'                AS TRANS_TYPE_NAME, 
   NULL                        AS CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT,
   f.ORG_REF          AS ORGANIZATION_REFERENCE, 
   o.ORG_DESC       AS ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION, 
   sg.SDG_ID           AS STUDY_GROUP_ID, 
   sg.SDG_REF          AS STUDY_GROUP_REFERENCE, 
   sg.SDG_DESC         AS STUDY_GROUP_DESCRIPT, 
   Sum(f.GL_AMOUNT)   AS TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, 
   f.FIN_ID           AS VOLUME_ID,
   f.GLACCT_REF       AS VOLUME_REFERENCE,
   f.GLACCT_DESC      AS VOLUME_DESCRIPTION,
   f.FIN_PER_ID       AS VOLUME_PERIOD_ID, 
   p.PER_REF              AS VOLUME_PERIOD_REFERENCE, 
   p.PER_DESC             AS VOLUME_PERIOD_DESCRIPT, 
   f.FIN_SCN_ID       AS VOLUME_SCENARIO_ID, 
   s.SCN_DESC           AS VOLUME_SCENARIO_DESCRIPT,
   NULL                        AS VOLUME_QUANTITY
   FROM StudyGroup sg 
   INNER JOIN Organization o ON sg.SDG_ID = o.SDG_ID
   INNER JOIN Financials f ON o.ORG_REF = f.ORG_REF
   INNER JOIN Scenario s ON f.FIN_SCN_ID = s.SCN_ID
   INNER JOIN Period p ON f.FIN_PER_ID = p.PER_ID
   GROUP BY 
   sg.SDG_ID,
   sg.SDG_REF,
   sg.SDG_DESC,
   f.ORG_REF,
   o.ORG_DESC,
   f.FIN_ID,
   f.GLACCT_REF,
   f.GLACCT_DESC,
   f.FIN_PER_ID,
   p.PER_REF,
   p.PER_DESC,
   f.FIN_SCN_ID,
   s.SCN_DESC
```

Also, I am not sure you are using UNION because you want to eliminate duplicates between the two queries or not. If not you will get a little better performance by using UNION ALL so it doesn't have to check for duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, Sean. That resolved the error. I didn't think of removing all of non-table column values, since Oracle requires them.  The UNION is designed to primarily marry up the actual financial data with the Study Group, Organizations, Scenarios and Periods.  It was provided by another person and I had to tweak it considerably to get it working in Oracle.  Then I was asked to put it in SQL Server.  Again, Thank You...

Comment: Wow I pretty much guessing. I am not an Oracle person. That is strange it requires you to group by literals. Glad that worked for you. I had a feeling the two sets were not going to possibly return duplicates given the nature of the queries. You might look into the differences between UNION and UNION ALL. There are times the performance difference is truly shocking.

Comment: I will look into the UNION ALL, as eventually this view where the query lives will be querying Billions of records. Thanks again...